# How to add multi array in loop JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My question is not quite clear but i dont know how to explan. So i have my list.json like this

```js
function get_json(){
 var results = document.getElementById("results");

    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("GET", "mylist.json", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
   var d = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);

   results.innerHTML = "";
   for(var o in d){
              
    results.innerHTML += 
    '<div class="'+d[o].place+'"><h2>'+d[o].name+'</h2><div class="gallery"></div></div>';
                    
   } //for(var o in d)

     }
    }

    hr.send(null);
    results.innerHTML = 'Please wait...';
```

```css
{
 "product1":{
   "name": "apple",
   "place": "X",
   "image": [ {"pic": 1, "review": "Review for pic 1"},
      {"pic": 2, "review": "Review for pic 2"},
      {"pic": 3, "review": "Review for pic 3"}
     ]
 },
 "product2":{
   "name": "milk",
   "place": "Y",
   "image": [ {"pic": 1, "review": "Review for pic 1"},
      {"pic": 2, "review": "Review for pic 2"}
     ]
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="results">
</div>



<script>get_json();</script>
```

You can see, depending on the place X or Y, I will create a class X or Y for each product. In each div, I have product name and a .gallery div. The question is: how can i define "pic" and "review" of each product, and add them in .gallery div as img and p. It supports to look like this at the end. Please help me. i am new with json.

```html
<div id="results">
  <div class="X">
    <h2>Apple</h2>
    <div class="gallery>
        <img src="1.png">
        <p>Review of pic 1</p>
        <img src="2.png">
        <p>Review of pic 2</p>
        <img src="3.png">
        <p>Review of pic 3</p>    
     </div>                     
  </div>
                        
   <div class="Y">
    <h2>Milk</h2>
    <div class="gallery>
        <img src="1.png">
        <p>Review of pic 1</p>
        <img src="2.png">
        <p>Review of pic 2</p>  
     </div>                     
  </div>                       
                        
                        
</div>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You need a double nested loop. For example:

```
for(var o in d)
{
    results.innerHTML += 
    '<div class="'+d[o].place+'"><h2>'+d[o].name+'</h2><div class="gallery">';
    for(var i in d.image)
    {
         results.innerHTML += '<img src="' + d.image[i].pic + '.png" />';
         results.innerHTML += '<p>' + d.image[i].review + '</p>';
    }
    results.innerHTML += '</div></div>';       
}
```

Comment: i did check but the d.image[i].pic doesn't show anything. The element shows <div class="gallery"</div></div> but nothing inside it. When i use results.innerHTML = d.product1.image.pic; it said undefined. same with review. Is there anything wrong with my json?